# Where is the house used to film "Demon Seed" (1977)?

Tags: film-location, demon-seed

Much of the 1977 film, *Demon Seed*, takes places in a magnificent house that is quite architectural and stately. I wonder what this house is and where it could be? IMDB often has location information, but in this case there is none.

Best external shot in the movie:
[image: external shot of house]

View from porch:
[image: view from porch]

Comment: A photo would really help here.  Often filming locations are reused, so someone might recognize it from another film/TV series.